# Is -NR3+ really meta directing?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, aromaticity, electrophilic-substitution

For electrophilic aromatic substitution, it is said that -NR<sub>3</sub><sup>+</sup> is meta directing, but since it only shows electron withdrawing inductive effect and inductive effect decreases with distance so it must para directing since at para position inductive effect will be minimum.So is -NR<sub>3</sub><sup>+</sup> meta or para directing?